# need help in salt-stack pillar data

Tags: salt-stack

I want to read the data from one pillar file into another. for example:

top.sls 
   - one 
   - two

one.sls 
env: test

two.sls 
dir: {{salt'pillar.get'}}_value

But it is not getting the value of pillar 'env' from one.sls in two.sls. Any idea how we can do that?

Thanks, 
Sanjiv

Comment: I would recommen specifying a `include` for getting the `one.sls` state file this way you are sure you are getting the env pillar  there.Second of all  have you tried running: `dir: {{ pillar['env'] }}` or however you plan on using it.And second of all are you sure the environment variable should be declared in the pillars ?I see it as more of a grain.

Answer (score 0):

This currently not available out of the box. There's an [issue](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/23910), but at this rate it probably wont make it in any of the 2016.x releases.

The cleanest workaround I've found is import:

**one.sls**:

```
{% set foo = 'bar' %}
baz: {{ foo }}
```

**two.sls:**

```
{% from 'one.sls' import foo %}
baz2: {{ foo }}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.